# Devise current_user returns nil when I create new users, Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm working on a Rails app where I use Devise for registrations. I use single table inheritance for managing user roles, [similar to this](http://www.funonrails.com/2011/12/multiple-resources-registrations-with.html). I have three User models `User < ActiveRecord`, `Admin < User` and `Collaborator < User`. Collaborator and Admins share sessions. My current problem is with creating new users, the User is saved to the database and user_signed_in? returns true, but current_user returns nil for some reason.

When User creates their accounts it should redirect to my AccountsController index action which looks like this:

```
def index
  @accounts = current_user.accounts
end
```

results in:

```
undefined method `accounts' for nil:NilClass
```

The same code works when I instead try to sign in.

My routes looks like this [(as of)](http://www.funonrails.com/2011/12/multiple-resources-registrations-with.html):

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions  => 'sessions'}, :skip => [:registrations] do
  delete '/logout', :to => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  get '/sign_in', :to => 'sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
  post '/sign_in', :to => 'sessions#create', :as => :user_session
end
devise_for :admins, :controllers => {:registrations  => 'admins/registrations'}, :skip => :sessions do
  get '/sign_up', :to => 'admins/registrations#new', :as => :new_admin
  post '/sign_up', :to => 'admins/registrations#create', :as => :admin
end
devise_for :collaborators, :controllers => {:registrations  => 'collaborators/registrations'}, :skip => :sessions
```

I have also created some helper method that I use [(the same as of)](http://www.funonrails.com/2011/12/multiple-resources-registrations-with.html):

```
# New Version using dynamic methods
  %w(Collaborator Admin).each do |k|
  define_method "current_#{k.underscore}" do
    current_user if current_user.is_a?(k.constantize)
  end

  define_method "authenticate_#{k.underscore}!" do |opts={}|
    send("current_#{k.underscore}") || not_authorized
  end
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.is_a?(User)
    accounts_path
  else
    super
  end
end

def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  accounts_path
end
```

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by customizing after_sign_up_path_for, like this:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  sign_in(resource)
  accounts_path 
end
```

Let me know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Ever figure this out?  I know its been a few years but running into a similar situation and would like to avoid using your fix. Its simple and will work but seems like you shouldn't have to